# Python recursive function reloaded from module

Tags: python, function, object, recursion, python-module

If we have recursive function func1 in module mod1 and we import it using both statements:

```
import mod1
```

and

```
from mod1 import func1
```

Basically we will have two links to the single object:

```
id(func1) == id(mod1.func1)
```

Then if we update func1 code inside mod1.py file and then reload mod1, but not the function (func1) itself:

```
imp.reload(mod1)
```

we will have two different objects:

```
id(func1) != id(mod1.func1)
```

However if we call func1(*args) - first call it calls func1, but all the following recursive calls it calls mod1.func1

Is that a desired behavior in python?

Here are code examples:
mod1.py:

```
def func1(n):
  print("n is: {}".format(n))
  if n==0: return 1
  return n*func1(n-1)
```

Then modified:

```
def func1(n):
  # print("n is: {}".format(n))
  if n==0: return 1
  return n*func1(n-1)
```

Here is REPL output:

```
>>> from mod1 import func1
>>> func1(2)
n is: 2
n is: 1
n is: 0
2
>>> import mod1
>>> mod1.func1(2)
n is: 2
n is: 1
n is: 0
2
>>> id(func1)
4304551720
>>> id(mod1.func1)
4304551720
>>> ## ** Here mod1 code is updated: ** ##
>>> import imp
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
>>> imp.reload(mod1)
<module 'mod1' from '/home/user/workspace/python/tests/mod1.py'>
>>> id(mod1.func1)
4305274128
>>> id(func1)
4304551720
>>> mod1.func1(2)
2
>>> func1(2)
n is: 2
2
>>>
```

It seems to be a little bit confusing.
Is that a desired behavior in python?

Comment: Interesting, but it'll be tough to answer the part about desirability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say whether the behavior is desirable (for whom), but it is expected.

There is not much difference between your sample of code and the following:

```
In [3]: class Foo:
   ...:     def qwe(self, once_again=True):
   ...:         print('original qwe')
   ...:         if once_again:
   ...:             self.qwe(once_again=False)
   ...:     qwe1 = qwe
   ...:
   ...:     def qwe(self, once_again=True):
   ...:         print('new qwe')
   ...:         if once_again:
   ...:             self.qwe(once_again=False)
   ...: a = Foo()
   ...: a.qwe1()
   ...:
   ...:
original qwe
new qwe
```

After the import statement is executed, `mod1` and `func1` are just variables that keep references on the corresponding objects. When you reload a module, you just assign another value to the variable with the name `mod1`.

BTW, you may observe a similar effect when you store a reference to a module level or class level logger in a variable: `LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, since nothing stops the user of your code to invoke `logging.config.dictConfig` somewhere in the middle of the application lifetime. If the newer configuration was meant to suppress output from your module, your code won't know anything about the new logger for your module and you will continue writing to the log.

I'd say, that the behavior is at least intended.

UPD: the question turned out a bit more complicated.

If the variable is missing in the current lexical scope of the function it is taken from the scope of the module (if it is not a closure, in which case the `__closure__` field is used). To get the scope of the module the function accesses the module level variables via `sys.modules[func1.__module__]` which has been updated by `reload`.